# Why in 13F filing, the same company was split into two rows?

Tags: stocks, sec

In this SEC filing of Goldman Sachs

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/886982/000076999321000319/xslForm13F_X01/InfoTable_2021-11-09_Final.xml

There are two rows:

[image]

I don't find any difference other than the amount/valuation.

Why not just combine them into one row?

What are the different of special reason to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't find any difference other than the amount/valuation.

Isn't the "Column 7 Other Managers" different?

> Why not just combine them into one row?

How do you combine 1 with 2? 1.5?

> Question 48
>
> Q: What do I list in Column 7, "Other Managers"?
>
> A: Column 7 is one of the places where you identify another reporting
> manager with whom you share investment discretion if that manager also
> meets the $100 million filing threshold. You create a numbered list of
> such other managers on the Summary Page. Column 7 is the place where
> you enter the number assigned to each manager (i.e., 1 or 2 if you are
> reporting on behalf of two other managers). This designation
> identifies the securities on your Form 13F that are linked to the
> other manager.
>
> If a manager with whom you share investment discretion does not meet
> the $100 million filing threshold, you merely aggregate that manager's
> Section 13(f) securities on your filing. Do not list the other
> manager's positions separately, or refer to the other manager in
> Column 7.

https://www.sec.gov/divisions/investment/13ffaq.htm

Comment: oh, thanks a lot!